# Stream video didn't have a duration exif

Tags: node.js, video, websocket, stream, record

I do a website to record webcam in real-time on my server.

To do this, I use Web Socket to send data of my webcam to my Node.js Server.

The record is working, but my video didn't have a duration. In other words, I can't navigate in the video. I can just read the file second by second and can't skip segment or going back in the timer. (see the GIF below)

[image: example of timer can't changing]

my server code to save video :

```js
server.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("Client connected");

  let writeStream = null;
  let id = Date.now();
  let filename = `${folderStream}/video-${id}.${extensionFile}`; // example : ./video/video-1620000000000.mp4

  socket.on("message", (message) => {
    if (!writeStream) {
      console.log("Stream started");
      writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
    }

    writeStream.write(message);
  });

  socket.on("close", () => {
    console.log("Stream closed");

    writeStream.end();
  });
});
```

I try to use ffmpeg, but my video is already in one file and not segmented. (maybe bad usage by me)

Answer (score 0):

For the future users who want to do the same thing, do this :

Create a temporary file who takes all raw data :

```js
server.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("Client connected");

  let tempFile = null;

  let id = Date.now();
  let filename = `video-${id}`; // exemple : video-1620000000000

  socket.on("message", (message) => {
    if (!tempFile) {
      console.log("Stream started");
      tempFile = fs.createWriteStream(`${folderStream}/${filename}.tmp`);
    }
    tempFile.write(message);
  });
```

And with the library "fluent-ffmpeg";

```bash
npm i fluent-ffmpeg
```

```js
const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
```

*Don't forget to [install ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) in your computer.*

You can create a file transcoded after the ending stream.

```js
  socket.on("close", () => {
    console.log("Fin d'un stream");

    tempFile.end();

    ffmpeg()
      .input(`${folderStream}/${filename}.tmp`)
      .format(extensionFile) // const extensionFile = "mp4"
      .output(`${folderTranscode}/${filename}.${extensionFile}`)
      .on("end", () => {
        console.log("Conversion complete");
      })
      .run();
  });
});
```